# What does the ESX helper0-0 process do?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a laptop used for development purposes (EliteBook 8540p) upon which I have installed ESXi 5.5 to run multiple servers and make use of snapshots for rollback.

After installing ESX and prior to installing any Virtual Machines, I noticed that in vSphere the CPU was reported at 50% usage.  Upon investigation I found there was a process group **helper** using 100% of a single CPU:

```
9:22:23am up 54 min, 407 worlds, 0 VMs, 0 vCPUs; CPU load average: 0.55, 0.55, 0.55
PCPU USED(%):  44  42  26 0.8 AVG:  28
PCPU UTIL(%):  40  39  23 1.0 AVG:  26
CORE UTIL(%):  78      24     AVG:  51

      ID      GID NAME             NWLD   %USED    %RUN    %SYS   %WAIT %VMWAIT    %RDY   %IDLE  %OVRLP   %CSTP  %MLMTD  %SWPWT 
       8        8 helper            150  107.15   96.23    0.00 14903.22       -    0.06    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   20854    20854 esxtop.43466        1    1.38    1.28    0.00   98.71       -    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
    2105     2105 hostd.33929        17    0.54    0.50    0.00 1699.43       -    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
       2        2 system             75    0.38    0.40    0.07 7499.10       -    0.22    0.00    0.08    0.00    0.00    0.00 
    2553     2553 sh.34162            1    0.18    0.22    0.00   99.78       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
    3256     3256 vpxa.34517          7    0.02    0.03    0.00  700.00       -    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
    2201     2201 rhttpproxy.3398     8    0.02    0.02    0.00  799.94       -    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   10320    10320 sshd.38140          1    0.02    0.03    0.00   99.97       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Expanding the GID showed there was one helper process significantly more active:

```
 9:25:00am up 56 min, 409 worlds, 0 VMs, 0 vCPUs; CPU load average: 0.55, 0.55, 0.55
PCPU USED(%):  48 0.6  46  18 AVG:  28
PCPU UTIL(%):  43 0.7  42  16 AVG:  26
CORE UTIL(%):  44      59     AVG:  51
          ID      GID NAME             NWLD   %USED    %RUN    %SYS   %WAIT %VMWAIT    %RDY   %IDLE  %OVRLP   %CSTP  %MLMTD  %SWPWT 
   32794        8 helper0-0           1  107.51   96.37    0.00    3.60       -    0.03    0.00    0.24    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32795        8 helper1-0           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32796        8 helper1-1           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32797        8 helper1-2           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32798        8 helper2-0           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32799        8 helper3-0           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32800        8 helper3-1           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32801        8 helper3-2           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 
   32802        8 helper4-0           1    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00       -    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I tried to view what the process was up to, but my usual tactic failed miserably:

```
~ # strace -p 32794
attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process
```

What is the purpose of the helper0-0 process and why would it be consuming 50% of my CPU resources with no Virtual Machines running?